# How to share data between activity and widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I read the hellowidget tutorial and Dev Guide' App Widgets. Then I know how to create a widget which contains button or text or something.

But what I really want to do is making it interact with my app. For example, I want to create a widget that has a text view, and when I click it, it sends a PendingIntent to my activity in which I can edit the text.

I can do the step "sends a PendingIntent". But after I edit text in acitivy, how does the widget read it?

Answer (score 12):

What you need to do is register a custom intent, for example ACTION_TEXT_CHANGED in your AppWidgetProvider like this for example:

```
public static final String ACTION_TEXT_CHANGED = "yourpackage.TEXT_CHANGED";
```

After this, you need to register in your AndroidManifest.xml that you want to receive this intents in the intent-filter section of your receiver tag like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".DrinkWaterAppWidgetProvider">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="yourpackage.TEXT_CHANGED" />                
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Then you have to extend the onReceive method in your AppWidgetProvider and make sure that you're handling your intent like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_TEXT_CHANGED)) {
        // handle intent here
        String s = intent.getStringExtra("NewString");
    }
}
```

After all the above is set up, you just need to broadcast the intent in your activity after the text has changed like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourAppWidgetProvider.ACTION_TEXT_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("NewString", textView.getText().toString());
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Where "NewString" should be changed to the name you to give the the string.

I hope it helps.

Comment: can you help me I'm having problems in passing my data from my widget to my activity here's mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587137/how-to-pass-data-and-open-an-activity-from-widget-android Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the RemoteViews class to do it. Create an instance of RemoteViews class inside your AppWidgetProvider's onRefresh method and use the methods in it...

```
RemoteViews views = RemoteViews(packageName, layoutId);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(viewId, pendingIntent);
```

Note that RemoteViews is limited in functionality when compared with the standard app views. But, you can achieve what you wanted to do with what they provide.

Comment: I CAN do the step "sends a PendingIntent." What you answered is this step.

Comment: Oops ok... Then, you have to broadcast another intent from your activity for which your widget can listen to. Have the data in the intent which can be used by the widget to refresh itself.