# How to parse a json rss feed into an android widget

Tags: android, json, android-widget, widget

please i need help, am a rookie, how can i create a widget that get its feed from from a Json in android. Is there a helpful tutorial that can help with this or a source code i can look at. I have checked online for a suitable tutorail but i found none that can help directly. this is the json url feed i want to pass into my android widget:url

public class MinistryNews extends SherlockListActivity {

```
private ActionBarMenu abm;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_QUERY = "query";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";
// private static final String TAG_CAT_CODE = "cat_code";
// private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
// private static final String TAG_CREATED_TIME = "created_time";
private static final String TAG_UPDATE_TIME = "update_time";
// private static final String TAG_AUTHOR_ID = "author_id";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray query = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> queryList;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ministry_news);

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    abm = new ActionBarMenu(MinistryNews.this);

    if (com.cepfmobileapp.org.service.InternetStatus.getInstance(this)
            .isOnline(this)) {

        // Toast t = Toast.makeText(this,"You are online!!!!",8000).show();
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You are online",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetQuery().execute();

    } else {
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Toast t =
        // Toast.makeText(this,"You are not online!!!!",8000).show();
        // Log.v("Home",
        // "############################You are not online!!!!");
        AlertDialog NetAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MinistryNews.this)
                .create();
        NetAlert.setMessage("No Internet Connection Found! Please check your connection and try again!");
        NetAlert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // here you can add functions
                // finish();

            }
        });
        NetAlert.show();
    }

    queryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
                    .getText().toString();

            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time))
                    .getText().toString();

            String description = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.content)).getText().toString();
            // String plain = Html.fromHtml(description).toString();

            // description.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_UPDATE_TIME, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_CONTENT, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    // new GetQuery().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetQuery extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MinistryNews.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..Loading news");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                query = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_QUERY);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < query.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = query.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);
                    String update_time = c.getString(TAG_UPDATE_TIME);
                    // String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    // String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    // JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    // String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    // String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    // String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    contact.put(TAG_CONTENT, content);
                    contact.put(TAG_UPDATE_TIME, update_time);
                    // contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    queryList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MinistryNews.this,
                queryList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_TITLE,
                        TAG_UPDATE_TIME, TAG_CONTENT }, new int[] {
                        R.id.title, R.id.time, R.id.content });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here is a nice tutorial for you to import json data http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-json-to-parse-data-into-android-application/28944
>   if its hard for you still.i can suggest you one thing ,you can import your rss to any website and customize it there as you want it to be and post them as json data it will be easier to do i guess.
>   its a raugh test for geting json data only the method i think its a bit easier and detail u can return the values instead of showing them in a text  from the textvw

```
public void getdata()
{
    String result=null;
    InputStream inputstream=null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://www.hadid.aero/news_and_json");
        HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity httpentity=response.getEntity();
        inputstream= httpentity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        resultview.setText(ex.getMessage()+"at 1st exception");
    }
    try{
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!= null)                  
        {
            sb.append(line +"\n");
        }
        inputstream.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        resultview.setText(ex.getMessage()+"at 2nd exception");
    }
    try{
        String s="test :";
        JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jarray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            s= s +"+json.getString("lastname")+"\n"+
                    "newsid&title : "+json.getString("id_news")+" "+json.getString("title")+"\n"+
                    "date :"+json.getString("date")+"\n"+
                    "description : "+json.getString("description");
        }
        resultview.setText(s);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        this.resultview.setText(ex.getMessage()+"at 3rd exception");
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much, i have implemented the json feed but what i need now is how to pass the rss feed into the widget, i will update with my code

Comment: what i need is, how to get the data from the json url, in my code above to the widget itself

Comment: thank you am i to implement this code in my widget class

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) which will create Java object with JSON content and use this in Your widget

Comment: thank you @pepe-pa, but am new to android, is there a guide on how i can use this, i mean a tutorail that can guide on how to implement a json rss feed into an android widget

Comment: Check out this tutorial about JSON RSS http://javatechig.com/android/json-feed-reader-in-android and this widget tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html

Comment: @pepa-pa thank you so much you have been helpful,but the vogella doesnt show how to pass an rss feed into the widget, if you can help, i will gladly accept your answer. thank you so much. i have also updated with my code, but now i need to pass this to the widget

Comment: Maybe this post will help You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914234/how-to-share-data-between-activity-and-widget it show how to pass data from Activity to widget

Comment: thank you once again i will try this and get back to you

Comment: i have gone through it, this does not directly answer it, what i need is, how to get the data from the json url, in my code above to the widget itself